# How to use jQuery after new objects are injected into DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am making a Sentence Generator. So far, it can take a list of words. Then it gets data from sentence.yourdictionary.com to take a sentence. I display the first sentence from sentence.yourdictionary.com using `$("ul.example>li").first()`.Then it is put into a paragraph  `<p id="sents">`.

So if you entered in the words *yo* and *nose* your output would be

```
<p id="sents"><li id="yo"><strong>Yo</strong> ' money
back a hund'd times, de preacher says!</li><li id="nose">I will no longer be caught with a
bleeding <strong>nose</strong>, heart palpatations, week long benders or hurting myself in any major way.</li></p>
```

I want a function to be called when you hover over the new list items.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("li").hover( function () {
        $(this).append("<span>Testing</span>");
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        console.log(id);
    }, function () {
        $(this).find("span:last").remove();
    });
});
```

This doesnt work after the new list items are injected into the DOM. I tried adding an event listener for *mousemove*, but then when you hover over it the word "test" shows up a bunch of times! How can I make it happen  after the new list items are injected?

Here is a jfiddle if you want some clarification: http://jsfiddle.net/varhawk5/cNKyx/1/

Thank you so much. Sorry I'm just learning javascript!

**EDIT**

To fix this issue, I used the .on() function as the comments suggested. There is no "hover" event though, so I think this is the only way.

```
$("body").on("mouseenter", "li#topWord", function() {
        var word = $(this).data("word");
        var sents = sentences[word]
        $(this).html("<div class='restOfSents' data-word='" + word +"'></div>");
        for(var i=1; i<sentences[word].length; i++) {
            $(".restOfSents").append($(sentences[word][i]));
        }
    console.log(sents);
});

$("body").on("mouseleave", "li", function() {
    // Remove the new div
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$(document).on('hover','li', function () {
    $(this).append("<span>Testing</span>");
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    console.log(id);
}, function () {
    $(this).find("span:last").remove();
});
});
```

Comment: I did this before, but I wrote "mousemove" not "hover"! Silly me! Haha

Comment: the `hover` pseudo event doesn't exist in jquery 1.9, you'd have to use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

Answer (score 1):

You should make use of [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) rather than `.hover()`:

```
$('li').on('mouseenter', function() { ... })
```

Also you shouldn't use IDs for this. Make use of [`data-*`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes) attributes instead. Otherwise your code will break when a user enters the same word twice (as IDs are unique).

```
var id = $(this).attr('data-example');
```

Comment: I'm confused actually. There aren't any `li` elements in the JSFiddle code you provided.

Comment: the `hover` pseudo event doesn't exist in jquery 1.9, you'd have to use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly new <li> elements are injected into the DOM after you write words

Comment: @varhawk5 in the JSFiddle example you've given there are no `li` elements, just paragraphs containing anchor tags.

Answer (score 1):

You're right!  The reason for this, is that $(document).ready() only gets called on page load.  You can either manually add a new event hook to each new element as you add it, or take advantage of jQuery's "on" functionality which will automatically detect new dom elements which match your criteria.